# uniqueVersion tag ignored by maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to do something I thought was simple: Stop unique versions of SNAPSHOT builds being created due to space considerations.

So I setup my pom with this:

```
<distributionManagement>
    ...
    <!--Snapshot deploy repository-->
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>maven-general-repo.googlecode.com</id>
        <name>General Maven Repo on Google Code</name>
        <url>dav:https://general-maven-repo.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/snapshots</url>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>
    ...
</distributionManagement>
```

And then simply run `mvn clean deploy`. However the build is *still* prefixed with `-20110305.210936-1`

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a tag or switch I'm missing?

Maven version: 3.0.3

maven-deploy-plugin version:  --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maven 3 no longer allows you to control this option.

Comment: Do you happen to know why? This seems like an important feature for those of us who aren't running dedicated repository software

Comment: A possible reason is listed in [Nexus' Jira](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-4534?focusedCommentId=138269&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-138269); the fact that the feature was removed is mentioned in the [maven 3 compatibility docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-Non-uniqueSnapshotDeployments). If you only install into your local repo, maven will - to the best of my knowledge - not post fix a unique version identifier. (Just realised I'm a bit late to the party ;)